# Magento 2.2.5: Catalog Search return blank page

Tags: magento2.2, catalogsearch

I know this question has been ask alots , but i cant find the answer that can fix my problem, so here we are.
[image]

At first,i enter something into the search text, for example, i enter an "S" word. Then i push enter.

So now you can see, it return a blank page.
[image]

I'm already turn the developer mode on, and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\bootstrap.php and reindex use command and admin page, setup:upgrade, di:compile, deploy.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EDIT: 

After i rollback the db and run setup:upgrade, now it appear this, but still not correct

[image]

C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\var\log\system.log:

```
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Analytics::bi_essentials was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Marketplace::partners was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_SalesRule::promo_quote was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_marketing was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_sales was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_tax was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_invoiced was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_shipping was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_refunded was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_coupons was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_shopcart_product was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_shopcart_abandoned was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_bestsellers was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_sold was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_viewed was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_lowstock was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers_accounts was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers_totals was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers_orders was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_statistics was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_statistics_refresh was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Search::report_search_term was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::catalog_reviews_ratings_ratings was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::catalog_reviews_ratings_reviews_all was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review_customer was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review_product was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sitemap::catalog_sitemap was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_TaxImportExport::system_convert_tax was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Variable::system_variable was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::marketing_automation was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::automation_studio was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::exclusion_rules was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::marketing_automation_report was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::importer was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::automation was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::campaign was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::cron was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::dashboards was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::logviewer was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::abandoned was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Shopial_Facebook::marketing_social was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Shopial_Facebook::shopial_facebook was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::shipping was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::carriers was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::locations was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::packaging was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:40] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::dispatches was processed [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.tooltip' element cannot be added as child to 'content', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'search.result' element cannot be added as child to 'content', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'search.search_terms_log' element cannot be added as child to 'content', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:10:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:11:31] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.tooltip' element cannot be added as child to 'content', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:11:31] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'search.result' element cannot be added as child to 'content', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:11:31] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'search.search_terms_log' element cannot be added as child to 'content', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:13:35] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:13:35] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:13:35] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:13:35] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:13:35] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:14:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:14:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:14:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:14:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-24 08:14:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
```

Comment: Did you check console and var/log?

Comment: give me one second, i'm trying reindex by admin , and di:compile and deploy, it take alot of time .. @@

Comment: You can try with Virtual Host OR use `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @TBSMage does Virtual Host make the command faster or something? Thanks

Comment: I ain't sure but I am using same environment for Mage 2.2.5 in Xampp.  I can able to search catalogs with it.

Comment: hmmm .. i'm using my custom theme, does that give u more information?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh.. my bad, I put the default.xml in my Custom Theme in `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\Fudu\customtheme\Magento_Theme\layout` , and i referenceContainer the content then put the empty page by using phtml.

So, my solution is delete the default.xml, so it doesn't make the content empty anymore.